# Addressbook: Turn an "at least one list suffices" query to an "all lists need to be present"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database that contains among others these five tables:
[Addressbook SQL Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbrWQ.jpg)

Lists can be assigned to contacts and print jobs. If I want to process a print job (e.g. printing contacts on envelopes) I need to fetch all those contacts that got the same lists assigned as that print job.

So far I got this SQL query, but it fetches all contacts that have *at least* one list in common this the print job in question, but I need *all* assigned lists to match:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `contact`.* FROM `contact` JOIN (
  SELECT `contact_id` FROM `contact_list` JOIN (
    SELECT `list_id` FROM `job_list` WHERE `job_id` = :id
  ) AS `inner` ON `inner`.`list_id` = `contact_list`.`list_id`
) AS `outer` ON `outer`.`contact_id` = `contact`.`id`
```

I view it as an "at least one list is good enough" but I need an "all lists need to be assigned to a job as well".

How does such a query look like?

**Edit:**

Here are some queries that generate sample data: [SQL Sample Data](https://pastebin.com/sQcz7VdL)

And here are the expected results for each print job:

```
job_id      contact_id
1           1, 2, 3
2           5
3           4, 6
```

Contact 7 should never show up

**Result**

```sql
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE id IN (
  WITH flattenJob (job_id, jlist) AS (
    SELECT job_id, group_concat(list_id) 
    FROM job_list
    GROUP BY job_id
  ),
  flattenCont (contact_id, clist) AS (
    SELECT contact_id, group_concat(list_id)
    FROM contact_list
    GROUP BY contact_id
  )
  SELECT contact_id
  FROM flattenJob
  JOIN flattenCont ON jlist = clist
  WHERE job_id = :id
)
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the objective is to print one envelope per contact (save money, save the environment, Yay!); essentially dedupe the lists. An idea would be to turn a "compound job" (like job 3) into it's own entity. One way would be to use virtual tables, something like this:

```
WITH flattenJob (job_id,jlist) as
 (select job_id,group_concat(list_id) 
 from job_list
 group by job_id
 ),
 flattenCont (contact_id,clist)
 as (select contact_id,group_concat(list_id)
 from contact_list
 group by contact_id
 )
 select job_id,contact_id,jlist,clist
 from flattenJob
 JOIN flattenCont on jlist = clist
```

This is the result from the sample data:

```
job_id      contact_id  jlist       clist
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           1           1
1           2           1           1
1           3           1           1
2           5           2           2
3           4           1,2         1,2
3           6           1,2         1,2
```

This should give you a good starting point to create a successful query.